# 3-level deep if-else tree for constructing a neural network

Tags: python, design-patterns, neural-network

The following code fragment constructs different types of neural networks outputs based on the options supplied. Currently, my code just has a huge note that describes what all the options are supposed to do. I wanted to learn how I can make this code less complex or perhaps break its complexity into simpler pieces. Any suggestions?

```
#------------------------------------------------------------#
# NOTE: Meaning of all the options.                          #
# stagger_schedule=extended: We copy input vec to output.    #
# stagger_schedule=external: We dont copy input to output.   #
# -----------------------------------------------------------#
# do_backward_pass: We use the output of the backward LSTM   #
#   Default:True.                                            #
# -----------------------------------------------------------#
# chop_bilstm: Should we chop the first and last vectors from#
# the sequence. Default:False                                #
#------------------------------------------------------------#
# extended_multiplicative: Multiply the forward and back LSTM#
#    and concatenate the input embedding.                    #
# external_multiplicative: Multiply the forward and back LSTM#
#    and but dont concatenate the input embedding.           #
#------------------------------------------------------------#
if (self.prm('stagger_schedule') == 'extended'):
    if self.prm('chop_bilstm'):
        if self.prm('do_backward_pass'):
            self.output_tv = T.concatenate(
                [forward, backward, input_tv], axis=1)[1:-1]
            pass
        else:
            self.output_tv = T.concatenate(
                [forward, input_tv], axis=1)[1:-1]
            pass
        pass
    else:
        if self.prm('do_backward_pass'):
            self.output_tv = T.concatenate(
                [forward, backward, input_tv], axis=1)
            pass
        else:
            self.output_tv = T.concatenate(
                [forward, input_tv], axis=1)
            pass
        pass
    pass
elif self.prm('stagger_schedule') == 'external':
    if self.prm('chop_bilstm'):
        if self.prm('do_backward_pass'):
            self.output_tv = T.concatenate(
                [forward[1:-1], backward[2:]], axis=1)
            pass
        else:
            self.output_tv = forward[1:-1]
            pass
        pass
    else:
        if self.prm('do_backward_pass'):
            self.output_tv = T.concatenate(
                [forward, backward], axis=1)
            pass
        else:
            self.output_tv = forward
            pass
        pass
    pass
elif self.prm('stagger_schedule') == 'extended_multiplicative':
    if self.prm('chop_bilstm') or (not self.prm('do_backward_pass')):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    self.output_tv = T.concatenate(
        [forward * backward, input_tv], axis=1)
    pass
elif self.prm('stagger_schedule') == 'external_multiplicative':
    if self.prm('chop_bilstm') or (not self.prm('do_backward_pass')):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    self.output_tv = forward * backward
    pass
else:
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ways you can tidy up this code:

- **Add some comments.** It’s quite hard for me to tell whether this code is correct, or whether I‘ve introduced a bug by refactoring, because I don’t know what this code is supposed to do.
- **Get rid of the unnecessary pass statements.** The `pass` statement literally [does nothing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=pass#the-pass-statement) except provide a placeholder for unwritten code. If you delete them all, you’ll save a lot of lines and be able to fit more code on screen.
- Under the `extended` branch, the code is almost the same except we remove the first and last character of `self.output_tv`. If we defer that until the end, we can have one set of branches as follows:

  ```
  if (self.prm('stagger_schedule') == 'extended'):
      if self.prm('do_backward_pass'):
          self.output_tv = T.concatenate([forward, backward, input_tv], axis=1)
      else:
          self.output_tv = T.concatenate([forward, input_tv], axis=1)

      if self.prm('chop_bilstm'):
          self.output_tv = self.output_tv[1:-1]
  ```

  22 lines cut down to 7, and this is only 2 levels deep.
- The code in the `external` branch can be similarly consolidated: you do the same effect in both subbranches, but with slightly truncated `forward` and `backward` variables. Here’s an alternative version:

  ```
  elif self.prm('stagger_schedule') == 'external':
      if self.prm('chop_bilstm'):
          forward = forward[1:-1]
          backward = backward[2:]

      if self.prm('do_backward_pass'):
          self.output_tv = T.concatenate([forward, backward, axis=1)
      else:
          self.output_tv = forward
  ```

  20 lines cut down to 8, and this is only 2 levels deep.

- You could consider wrapping each branch into its own method, and calling into that. For example, something like:

  ```
  if (self.prm('stagger_schedule') == 'extended'):
      self._set_output_tv_extended(forward, backward, input_tv)
  elif self.prm('stagger_schedule') == 'external':
      self._set_output_tv_external(forward, backward, input_tv)
  elif self.prm('stagger_schedule') == 'extended_multiplicative':
      self._set_output_tv_extended_multiplicative(forward, backward, input_tv)
  elif self.prm('stagger_schedule') == 'external_multiplicative':
      self._set_output_tv_external_multiplicative(forward, backward, input_tv)
  else:
      raise NotImplementedError()
  ```

  That saves you an immediate level of nesting and pushes the specific logic of each branch out of this method.

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring is best done one code at least slightly understood. This is not the case here so I may have introduced new issues. Because I had no idea what I was doing, I just applied some usual recipes (assuming the objects you are using are well behaved):

**Avoid the unnecessary**

You have `pass` statements all over the place which serve no purpose whatsoever.

Most of the parenthesis you've used are useless.

You are retrieving the different parameters in many different places. It could be a good idea to retrieve them once and for all at the beginning. This is particularly useful because you are using strings are keys and I don't want to bother about having to check the string used as I am reading or writing the code.

**Do not repeat yourself**

If you look at your code, it is quite obvious that there are many similarities all over the place. The best way to get rid of it is to write your code in such a way that it is easy to detect it : see what is similar and see what changes. In your case, that means taking into account the comments above but also reformating your code so that statements are on a single line (this is not a good thing to do usually but it helps the eye to detect similarities ; also long lines might be the sign there is something to improve).

When you've seen that only a few detail are changed from one call to another, you can try to change your code so that everything goes in the same logic with a different pre-processing and/or post-processing. This technique is really useful in code like yours where you have many nested `if` : the number of blocks grows as 2^number_of_levels but you may reduce this to a single block with only number_of_levels preprocessing logics.

Also, reordering the order in which conditions are checked sometimes makes things more concise.

In your case, I think your code can be rewritten :

```
def concat(lst):
    return T.concatenate(lst, axis=1)


stagger_schedule = self.prm('stagger_schedule')
chop_bilstm = self.prm('chop_bilstm')
do_backward_pass = self.prm('do_backward_pass')
if stagger_schedule == 'extended':
    add_input = [backward] if do_backward_pass else []
    self.output_tv = concat([forward] + add_input + [input_tv])
    if chop_bilstm:
        self.output_tv = self.output_tv[1:-1]
elif stagger_schedule == 'external':
    forward2 = forward[1:-1] if chop_bilstm else forward
    backward2 = backward[2:] if chop_bilstm else backward
    if do_backward_pass:
        self.output_tv = concat([forward2, backward2])
    else:
        self.output_tv = forward2  # could this correspond to a call to concat ?
elif chop_bilstm or not do_backward_pass:
    raise NotImplementedError()
elif stagger_schedule == 'extended_multiplicative':
    self.output_tv = concat([forward * backward, input_tv])
elif stagger_schedule == 'external_multiplicative':
    self.output_tv = forward * backward
else:
    raise NotImplementedError()
```